# Complex SQL queries (DELETE)?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working with three tables, and for simplicity's sake let's call them table A, B, and C. Both tables A and B have a column called id, as well as one other column, Aattribute and Battribute, respectively. Column c also has an id column, and two other columns which hold values for A.id and B.id. Now, in my code, I have easy access to values for both Aattribute and Battribute, and want to delete the row at C, so effectively I want to do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM C WHERE aid=(SELECT id FROM A WHERE Aattribute='myvalue') AND bid=(SELECT id FROM B WHERE Battribute='myothervalue')
```

But this obviously doesn't work. Is there any way to make a single complex query, or do I have to run three queries, where I first get the value of A.id using a SELECT with 'myvalue', then the same for B.id, then use those in the final query?
[Edit: it's not letting me comment, so in response to the first comment on this: I tried the above query and it did not work, I figured it just wasn't syntactically correct. Using MS Access, for what it's worth. ]

Comment: I tried the above query and it did not work, I figured it just wasn't syntactically correct. Using MS Access, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use IN instead of =.

```
DELETE
FROM   C
WHERE  aid IN
       (SELECT id
       FROM    A
       WHERE   Aattribute='myvalue'
       )
AND    bid IN
       (SELECT id
       FROM    B
       WHERE   Battribute='myothervalue'
       )
```

Comment: Just tried that, did not work. The specific error I'm getting is: "No value given for one or more required parameters." As stated above, I am using MS Access, I don't know if this affects it. I am googling around now for how to use the IN with DELETE in access sql. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That means it can't work out one or other of the field names. It may be a syntax problem - its been a while since I played with access - but fundamentally its not able to work out the fieldnames

Comment: Okay, turned out I had a bad column name in my second SELECT statement. I am no longer getting an error, though my row is not being deleted. I'll keep working on this, thanks.

Comment: Got it all working, just some more minor things on my end. Appreciate all the help!